# How to get different items on qlistwidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox, qlistwidget

is it possible to make it so that when selecting different rows from qtablewidget, different text is displayed in qlistwidget? data is added to qlistwidget from qcombobox, and to qcombobox from qstringlist

```
void MainWindow::on_addService_clicked()
{
   auto item = ui->serviceBox->currentText();
   ui->serviceListWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

I called itemSelectionChanged signal processing, but I do not know what to do?

I tried to clear the data from qlistwidget every time I selected a new line, but that's not what I wanted, when I selected a new line, there was a new text in qlistwidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `itemSelectionChanged` signal of the tablewidget and connect it a slot which manipualtes the data in the listwidget.

For details:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems